# Using virtualenv with sublime text 2

Tags: python, virtualenv, sublimetext2

I am using sublime text 2 for python development along with virtualenv!

The standard sublime text 2 build system uses the standard python install rather than my virtualenv where my packages are installed.

How can I get sublime text 2 to build using my virtualenv?

I currently use the terminal to activate my environment and run my scripts.

UPDATE: Never got it working, but seeing as i am using flask and it builds when you make a change, it's not a big issue

Comment: both but I plan to use OS X more!

Comment: Haha... "both". Not very helpful.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

**Note comments about this solution being incorrect.**

You have to edit your [sublime-project file](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/projects.html) and add the following:

```
"build_systems":
[
    {
    "name": "Run Tests",
    "cmd": ["source", "/path/to/your/virtualenv/bin/activate"],
    "working_dir": "/path/to/to/you/django_project",
    "cmd": ["python", "manage.py", "test"]
    }
]
```

Comment: I doubt that it would work, a dictionary with 2 "cmd" entries. The second "cmd" will simply overwrite the first.

Comment: But I think that if you remove the first "cmd" and replace "python" in the second "cmd" by a path to your virtualenv's python binary, it will work. IIRC, directly invoking a virtualenv's python works just as well as activating the virtualenv first.

Comment: By changing the first `cmd` with `"env": {"PYTHONPATH": "/path/to/your/virtualenv/bin/activate"},` do you manage to get something ?

Comment: This does not work, and I cannot understand how this could have been marked as correct. The "source" command is a builtin command, not a binary, so it is not found in the PATH, and so it executes with "File not found error".

Probably a mix of PYTHONPATH and evn would help, but I'm still trying to do that.

Answer (score 15):

You can also set the path for the build system to the `bin` directory of your virtualenv, like so:

```
"build_systems":
[
    {
        "selector": "source.python",
        "env": {"PYTHONPATH":"/Users/user/project"},
        "path":"/Users/user/work/myvirtualenv/bin:$PATH",
        "name": "Run virtualenv python",
        "cmd": ["python", "-u", "$file"],
        "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",

        "variants": [
            {   "name": "Run all Tests",
                "working_dir": "/Users/user/project",
                "cmd": ["nosetests"]
            } 
        ]
    }
]
```

This also allows other tools, like `nose` in the example, to find the correct python binary from the virtualenv.

Comment: Just gave you +1 but want to point out that "name" is only valid inside a variant. Refer to: [sublime-text-2-docs][st2]

[st2]: http://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/sublime-text-2/reference/build_systems.html

Comment: @user: Where do I need to add this file in ST?

Comment: @user1050619: from the [st 3 docs](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/file_processing/build_systems.html): *Build systems must be located somewhere under the Packages folder (e.g. Packages/User). Many packages include their own build systems.* The Packages folder lives in `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/` with ST 3 on my Mac.

Answer (score 13):

In windows this works for me:

```
"build_systems":
[
    {
    "name": "Run Tests",
    "working_dir": "/path/to/to/your/django_project",
    "cmd": ["/path/to/your/virtualenv/bin/python.exe", "manage.py", "test"]
    }
]
```

Comment: Note @nebffa's answer below which reminds users to then activate the new build system by selecting it under Tools > Build System!

Answer (score 12):

Sublime's Build System supports variables which can be used with Sublime project files to make this a bit more portable across projects.

If your virtual environments are in a standard spot, create a new project file (Project -> Save Project As) into the root directory of your project just above your virtual environment directory. Then create a new build file with something like this:

```
{

    "cmd": ["$project_path/venv/bin/python", "-u", "$file"]

}
```

It seems to then pick up the rest automatically - the same as if you typed ./venv/bin/python from the command line - no need to mess with paths, environment variables, etc.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using Flask, but I think it's apply to nearly every case.
My actual build is like this, where "benicio" is the directory of my project:

```
{
    "cmd": ["source ~/projs/benicio/venv/bin/activate && python ~/projs/benicio/benicio_tests.py"],
    "shell": true
}
```

Comment: I use `. venv/bin/activate; python file.py` Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Sorry to add yet another answer to this - but this caused me a large amount of grief figuring this out.

Not only do you need to make a build system like:

```
"build_systems":
[
{
    "name": "Maths",
    "env": {"PYTHONPATH":"/home/nebffa/Desktop"},
    "path":"$project_path/bin",
    "cmd": ["$project_path/bin/python3.3", "-u", "$file"]
}
]
```

but you HAVE to change a setting in Sublime Text - go to Tools --> Build System --> "Maths". In my case I need to choose "Maths" because that's what I named my build system. If you don't do this - Sublime Text does not use your build system!!

Answer (score 2):

I have just got sublime text 3 to working in a virtualenv. Although the OP specified ST2, there all likely more like myself who are using ST3. Thanks to user1248490 and Russell Beattie I arrived at the following:

```
{
    "shell_cmd": "$project_path/vi_sys_pkgs/bin/python3 -u \"$file\"",
    "path": "$project_path/vi_sys_pkgs/bin",
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
}
```

Note that "cmd" is now "shell_cmd" in ST3. See [ST3 blog](http://www.sublimetext.com/blog/articles/sublime-text-3-beta)

Comment: This is the only solution that works for me as well, running ST3 + Ubuntu 13.10, with virtualenvs tucked away in my homefolder

Answer (score 1):

Under MAC OSX, this works for me

```
{
"cmd": ["/your/virtualenv/bin/python", "-u", "$file"]
}
```

What i did was keep it simple:

Went to root drive and created python folder:

```
sudo mkdir python
```

then went in there and created the virtualenv

```
virtualenv --no-site-packages virtualenvname
```

then created a newbuild in ST2 with the above command and it works

Answer (score 1):

This is what I have as a build system (assuming my virtualenv is created as a folder called 'env' in my current project directory). This at least means I don't need to constantly change the build system between projects:

```
{
   "cmd": ["env/bin/python", "-u", "$file"]
}
```

I saved this as a New Build System (Tools -> Build System -> New Build System).

Answer (score 0):

I use this to build my Flask project. I have added the following code to my Project Settings: Project -> Edit Project

```
{
     "folders":
     [
          {
               "path": "/C/MyDev/chilinzb/"
          }
     ],
     "build_systems":
    [
        {
            "name": "Flask",
            // activate the specific virtualenv for the project
            "cmd": ["C:/MyDev/virtualenvs/env_chilinzb/Scripts/python", "$file"]
        }
    ]
}
```

and then I just switch to my `run.py` file and hit `Ctrl+B`

Answer (score 0):

this combination worked great:2 steps

1) add the 2 appropriate keys to the 'env' key.
A) DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE 
B) PYTHONPATH

2) update cmd to reflect the version of python you want to use.

```
{

"env":{"DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE":"my_project.settings",
    "PYTHONPATH":"d:\\Projects\\virts\\my_project\\Scripts;d:\\Projects\\virts\\my_project\\Lib;d:\\Projects\\virts\\my_project\\Lib\\site-packages;D:\\Projects\\my_project"
    },
"cmd": ["c:/Python27/python.exe","$file"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an answer for anyone who uses Heroku and uses their foreman tool, and it works great. Simply create a new build system like so:

```
{
    "cmd": ["foreman", "run", "python", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
}
```

This pulls in all of the environment variables available to Foreman, *including* your virtualenv's $PATH variable, which adds the virtualenv Python to your python path.

Answer (score 0):

source did not work for me inside the build on lubuntu.
use '.' or dot instead of 'source'.

this did work:

{

```
    "env": {
    "DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE":"django_project_name.settings",
    "PYTHONPATH":"/home/my_username/current/django_project_name:/home/my_username/.virtualenvs/django_project_name/lib/python2.7:/home/my_username/.virtualenvs/django_project_name/lib/python2.7/site-packages/"
},
"working_dir":"$project_path",
"cmd":[". /home/my_username/.virtualenvs/django_project_name/bin/activate && python $file"],
"shell":true
```

}

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:

```
{
    "cmd": ["C:/Users/user/virtualenvs/env1/Scripts/python.exe", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
}
```

saved build in:

`"C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages\User\"`

as

`"Python_env1.sublime-build"`

Select

`Tools> Build System> Python_env1`

done!

using windows 8.1, st2

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you keep your project-specific virtualenv in an .env-folder on the top level of your project.

1. Sublime > Project > Save project as... (if you haven't already. This will allow you to set custom build options for the project
2. Project > Edit Project:

   ```
   {
      "folders":[
          {
              "path": ".",
              "folder_exclude_patterns": [".env"],
          }
      ],
      "build_systems":[
          {
              "name": "Run in VirtualEnv",
              "shell_cmd": "source $project_path/.env/bin/activate && python -u $file"
          }
      ]
   }
   ```
3. Tools > Build System > Run in VirtualEnv
4. Tools > Build

Please note that this was tested with Sublime Text 3.