# Use Sublime with virtualenv

Tags: python, sublimetext2, virtualenv

So, I read through all of [Using virtualenv with sublime text 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11965707/using-virtualenv-with-sublime-text-2), but seeing how the accepted answer is clearly incorrect, I'm still very confused.

I'm trying to run my `chorus.py` file from within Sublime.  I've altered my build system to look like this:

```
"build_systems":
[
    {
        "name": "Scraper",
        "cmd" : ["/Users/thumbtackthief/.virtualenvs/chorus", "$file"]
    }
]
```

(based on the fact that when I enter `os.environ['VIRTUAL_ENV']` from the terminal that's the path that spits out--maybe I'm doing that wrong?)

When I build my file, I get `[Errno 13] Permission denied`.  I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Sublime, but if `cmd` is actually supposed to be a shell command to be executed, just a path to a Python file (+args) won't do. Python files aren't executable binaries, and the `#!/bin/python` shebang magic is performed by the shell. So try adding the Python to the virtualenv's python interpreter to the list as the first element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah.  The `"cmd"` should point to the python folder within the virtualenv:

`"cmd" : ["/Users/thumbtackthief/.virtualenvs/chorus/bin/python", "$file"]`

Yay.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my example for tensorflow. I created a build named "tensorflow.sublime-build" with the fellowing content.

```
{
    "shell_cmd": "source ~/tensorflow/bin/activate && python $file"
}
```