# Launching Sublime Text from virtualenv

Tags: python, sublimetext2, virtualenv, pylint, package-control

I'm trying out Sublime Text 2 and have installed [Package Control](https://sublime.wbond.net/). Now from Package Control in the Command Pallete I'm trying to install PyLint. However, this alert message pops up and am not sure how to proceed:

**Pylinter could not automatically determined the path to `lint.py`.**

**Please provide one in the settings file using the `pylint_path` variable.**

**NOTE:
If you are using a Virtualenv, the problem might be resolved by launching Sublime Text
from correct Virtualenv.**

I am using a virtualenv in my project and am not sure what it means to launch Sublime Test from the virtualenv. Any help is appreciated - thanks!

**UPDATE**

I think I may need to configure something with build_system variable in the *.sublime_project file to get the virtualenv working. There appears to be a range of somewhat confusing advice in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11965707/2441384).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have installed pylint into your virtualenv, editing the project-file like this should fix it

```
"settings":
    {
        "pylinter":
        {
             "python_bin": "path/to/your/virtualenv"
        }
    }
```

See: https://github.com/biermeester/Pylinter#project-settings and 
https://github.com/biermeester/Pylinter/issues/4